# How to modify a compressed itxt record of an existing file in python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, png, python-imaging-library

I know this looks too simple but I couldn’t find a straight forward solution.

Once saved, the itxt should be compressed again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so simple as you eyeballed it. If it were, you might have found out  there is *no* straightforward solution.

Let's start with the basics.

### Can PyPNG read all chunks?

An important question, because modifying an existing PNG file is a large task. Reading its documentation, it doesn't start out well:

> ### PNG: Chunk by Chunk
>
> #### Ancillary Chunks
>
> ..
> *iTXt*
> Ignored when reading. Not generated.

(https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/chunk.html)

But lower on that page, salvation!

> *Non-standard Chunks*
> Generally it is not possible to generate PNG images with any other chunk types. When reading a PNG image, processing it using the chunk interface, `png.Reader.chunks`, will allow any chunk to be processed (by user code).

So all I have to do is write this 'user code', and PyPNG can do the rest. (Oof.)

### What about the `iTXt` chunk?

Let's take a peek at what you are interested in.

> ### 4.2.3.3. iTXt International textual data
>
> .. the textual data is in the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set instead of Latin-1. This chunk contains:
>
> ```
> Keyword:             1-79 bytes (character string)
> Null separator:      1 byte
> Compression flag:    1 byte
> Compression method:  1 byte
> Language tag:        0 or more bytes (character string)
> Null separator:      1 byte
> Translated keyword:  0 or more bytes
> Null separator:      1 byte
> Text:                0 or more bytes
> ```

(http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.iTXt)

Looks clear to me. The optional compression ought not be a problem, since

> .. [t]he only value presently defined for the compression method byte is 0, meaning zlib ..

and I am pretty confident there is something existing for Python that can do this for me.

Back to PyPNG's chunk handling then.

### Can we see the chunk data?

PyPNG offers an *iterator*, so indeed checking if a PNG contains an `iTXt` chunk is easy:

> `chunks()`
> Return an iterator that will yield each chunk as a (chunktype, content) pair.

(https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html?#png.Reader.chunks)

So let's write some code in interactive mode and check. I got a sample image from http://pmt.sourceforge.net/itxt/, repeated here for convenience. (If the `iTXt` data is not conserved here, download and use the original.)

[image: itxt sample image]

```
>>> import png
>>> imageFile = png.Reader("itxt.png")
>>> print imageFile
<png.Reader instance at 0x10ae1cfc8>
>>> for c in imageFile.chunks():
...   print c[0],len(c[1])
... 
IHDR 13
gAMA 4
sBIT 4
pCAL 44
tIME 7
bKGD 6
pHYs 9
tEXt 9
iTXt 39
IDAT 4000
IDAT 831
zTXt 202
iTXt 111
IEND 0
```

Success!

What about writing back? Well, PyPNG is usually used to create complete images, but fortunately it also offers a method to explicitly create one from custom chunks:

> *png.write_chunks(out, chunks)*
> Create a PNG file by writing out the chunks.

So we can iterate over the chunks, change the one(s) you want, and write back the modified PNG.

### Unpacking and packing `iTXt` data

This is a task in itself. The data format is well described, but not suitable for Python's native `unpack` and `pack` methods. So we have to invent something ourself.

The text strings are stored in ASCIIZ format: a string ending with a zero byte. We need a small function to split on the first `0`:

```
def cutASCIIZ(str):
   end = str.find(chr(0))
   if end >= 0:
      result = str[:end]
      return [str[:end],str[end+1:]]
   return ['',str]
```

This quick-and-dirty function returns an array of a [*before*, *after*] pair, and discards the zero itself.

To handle the `iTXt` data as transparently as possible, I make it a class:

```
class Chunk_iTXt:
  def __init__(self, chunk_data):
    tmp = cutASCIIZ(chunk_data)
    self.keyword = tmp[0]
    if len(tmp[1]):
      self.compressed = ord(tmp[1][0])
    else:
      self.compressed = 0
    if len(tmp[1]) > 1:
      self.compressionMethod = ord(tmp[1][1])
    else:
      self.compressionMethod = 0
    tmp = tmp[1][2:]
    tmp = cutASCIIZ(tmp)
    self.languageTag = tmp[0]
    tmp = tmp[1]
    tmp = cutASCIIZ(tmp)
    self.languageTagTrans = tmp[0]
    if self.compressed:
      if self.compressionMethod != 0:
        raise TypeError("Unknown compression method")
      self.text = zlib.decompress(tmp[1])
    else:
      self.text = tmp[1]

  def pack (self):
    result = self.keyword+chr(0)
    result += chr(self.compressed)
    result += chr(self.compressionMethod)
    result += self.languageTag+chr(0)
    result += self.languageTagTrans+chr(0)
    if self.compressed:
      if self.compressionMethod != 0:
        raise TypeError("Unknown compression method")
      result += zlib.compress(self.text)
    else:
      result += self.text
    return result

  def show (self):
    print 'iTXt chunk contents:'
    print '  keyword: "'+self.keyword+'"'
    print '  compressed: '+str(self.compressed)
    print '  compression method: '+str(self.compressionMethod)
    print '  language: "'+self.languageTag+'"'
    print '  tag translation: "'+self.languageTagTrans+'"'
    print '  text: "'+self.text+'"'
```

Since this uses `zlib`, it requires an `import zlib` at the top of your program.

The class constructor accepts 'too short' strings, in which case it will use defaults for everything undefined.

The `show` method lists the data for debugging purposes.

### Using my custom class

With all of this, now examining, modifying, and adding `iTXt` chunks finally *is* straightforward:

```
import png
import zlib

# insert helper and class here

sourceImage = png.Reader("itxt.png")
chunkList = []
for chunk in sourceImage.chunks():
  if chunk[0] == 'iTXt':
    itxt = Chunk_iTXt(chunk[1])
    itxt.show()
    # modify existing data
    if itxt.keyword == 'Author':
      itxt.text = 'Rad Lexus'
      itxt.compressed = 1
    chunk = [chunk[0], itxt.pack()]
  chunkList.append (chunk)

# append new data
newData = Chunk_iTXt('')
newData.keyword = 'Custom'
newData.languageTag = 'nl'
newData.languageTagTrans = 'Aangepast'
newData.text = 'Dat was leuk.'
chunkList.insert (-1, ['iTXt', newData.pack()])

with open("foo.png", "wb") as file:
  png.write_chunks(file, chunkList)
```

When adding a totally new chunk, be careful **not** to `append` it, because then it will appear *after* the required last `IEND` chunk, which is an error. I did not try but you should also probably not insert it before the required first `IHDR` chunk or (as commented by Glenn Randers-Pehrson) in between consecutive `IDAT` chunks.

Note that according to the specifications, all texts in `iTXt` should be UTF8 encoded.

Comment: My post didn’t talked about pypng but python-pillow which has some support for ᴘɴɢ metadata, but seems too work…

Comment: @user2284570: I didn't notice that, it was in a tag only. And you were *very* scarce with details... As Python and PyPNG are new to me I took care to document how I went on writing this; hope that helps!

Comment: Correct, don't put iTXt ahead of IHDR or after IEND.  It's also not allowed among the IDAT chunks, if there are multiple IDAT chunks.  Otherwise, anywhere is OK.

Comment: Thanks, @GlennRanders-Pehrson, I missed that. Strangely, I had some serious problems finding out ways to *check* my adjusted PNGs! `pngcheck` can list contents of `tEXt` chunks but not `iTXt` (it shows keyword, compression, and language tag only); the otherwise immaculate ImageMagic's `identify` did not see anything at all. This sure appears to be a largely unused tag.

Comment: @Rad Lexus:  I use "pngcrush -n -v file.png" to list the chunks.  This will expand and print (among other things) the iTXt chunk contents.