# Python: Extract Metadata from PNG

Tags: python, png, metadata

I am able to extract the necessary information using R, but for consistency within the overall project, I would like to be able to do it with Python (preferably Python3).  I need the contents of a single tag called "Settings".  This tag contains XML which will then need to be parsed.

Getting the metadata in R is incredibly easy:

```
library(exifr)
library(XML)

path = file.path('path', 'to', 'file')

x = read_exif(file.path(path,'image.png'))
x$Settings
```

It doesn't look like Python can do it, which boggles my mind.  Or doing so requires me to have far more knowledge of Python and PNGs than I have at the moment.  How can I extract PNG metadata using Python?

---

### Here's the list of things I've tried:

**PyPng**
PyPNG seems promising.  Examining the length of each chunk, it seems likely the "Settings" tag lives in the zTXt chunk.

```
import png

filename = "C:\\path\\to\\image.png"

im = png.Reader(filename)

for c in im.chunks():
    print(c[0], len(c[1]))

>>>
IHDR 13
tIME 7
pHYs 9
IDAT 47775
zTXt 714
IEND 0
```

The above was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068414/how-to-modify-a-compressed-itxt-record-of-an-existing-file-in-python/37099807#37099807).  However, it's still unclear how to extract the zTXt data.

**hachoir3**

Using the [`hachoir3`](https://hachoir3.readthedocs.io/) package, I tried the following:

```
from hachoir.parser import createParser
from hachoir.metadata import extractMetadata

filename = "C:\\path\\to\\file\\image.png"
parser = createParser(filename)
metadata = extractMetadata(parser)

for line in metadata.exportPlaintext():
    print(line)
```

This gives me the following:

```
Metadata:
- Image width: 1024 pixels
- Image height: 46 pixels
- Bits/pixel: 16
- Pixel format: RGB
- Compression rate: 2.0x
- Image DPI width: 1 DPI
- Image DPI height: 1 DPI
- Creation date: 2016-07-13 19:09:28
- Compression: deflate
- MIME type: image/png
- Endianness: Big endian
```

I can't seem to get at the field I need, the "Settings" one referenced in the R code.  I've had no luck with other methods, such as `metadata.get`.  As far as I can tell, those seem to be the two options for parsing PNG metadata.  The docs read,

> Some good (but not perfect ;-)) parsers:
>
> Matroska video Microsoft RIFF (AVI video, WAV audio, CDA file) PNG
>   picture TAR and ZIP archive

Maybe it just doesn't have the functionality I need?

**Pillow**

Following the advice given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983135/metadata-extraction-from-png-images):

```
from PIL import Image
filename = "C:\\path\\to\\file\\image.png"
im = Image.open(filename)
```

This reads in the image, but `im.info` only returns `{'aspect': (1, 1)}`.  Reading through the documentation, it doesn't look like any of the methods get at the metadata. I read through the [PNG description](http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/The_Metadata_in_PNG_files) provided in the post.  Honestly, I don't know how to make use of its information nor how Pillow would facilitate me.

There are some posts which imply that what I need can be done, but they do not work.  For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697645/how-to-extract-metadata-from-a-image-using-python) suggests using the ExifTags library:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
filename = "C:\\path\\to\\file\\image.png"
im = Image.open(filename)
exif = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in im._getexif().items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS}
```

The problem is, `AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_getexif'`.  According to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/3.1.0.html?highlight=_getexif), the `._getexif` feature is experimental and only applies to JPGs.

Reading through the overall [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html), it really only talks about JPG and TIFF.  Processing PNG files doesn't seem to be part of the package at all.  So like `hachoir`, maybe it can't be done?

**PIL**

There's apparently another package PIL from which Pillow was forked.  It looks like it was abandoned in 2009.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract metadata from a image using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697645/how-to-extract-metadata-from-a-image-using-python)

Comment: PNG tags are only four characters long, so those "Settings" are not actually a *tag*. You are right, it looks like it's compressed data. Do you have a link to such a PNG file? If so, I can probably adjust my PyPNG code to extract it.

Comment: .. Okay, some bad news here. I found an R-created PNG with a `zTXt` chunk, and it contained just a profile in that chunk, no metadata. So I still need one containing your settings.

Answer (score 17):

You can get the EXIF metadata with Pillow by accessing the *info* dict of the loaded image.

> As of Pillow 6.0, EXIF data can be read from PNG images.
> However, unlike other image formats, EXIF data is not guaranteed to be present in info until `load()` has been called.
> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png

```
from PIL import Image

filename = 'path/to/img'
im = Image.open(filename)
im.load()  # Needed only for .png EXIF data (see citation above)
print(im.info['meta_to_read'])
```

I am using Python 3.7 and pillow 7.1.2 from the conda repo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inelegant and clumsy but working solution.

Adapted from here: https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/aekn58/hack-this-extra-image-metadata-using-python

You can call the command line exiftools app from within python and then parse the results.

Below is the code which works in Python 3.6.3 under Ubuntu 16.04:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['exiftool', '-h', '/home/jason/Pictures/kitty_mask.png'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print (type(result))
print ("\n\n",result.stdout)
normal_string = result.stdout.decode("utf-8")
print("\n\n", normal_string)
```

It produces the following results for my test image:

```
> <class 'subprocess.CompletedProcess'>
> 
> 
>  b'<!-- /home/jason/Pictures/kitty_mask.png
> -->\n<table>\n<tr><td>ExifTool Version Number</td><td>10.80</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File
> Name</td><td>kitty_mask.png</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Directory</td><td>/home/jason/Pictures</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File
> Size</td><td>25 kB</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File Modification
> Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:02 09:35:00+01:00</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File
> Access Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:09
> 16:23:24+01:00</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File Inode Change
> Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:02 09:35:00+01:00</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File
> Permissions</td><td>rw-r--r--</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File
> Type</td><td>PNG</td></tr>\n<tr><td>File Type
> Extension</td><td>png</td></tr>\n<tr><td>MIME
> Type</td><td>image/png</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Image
> Width</td><td>2448</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Image
> Height</td><td>3264</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Bit
> Depth</td><td>8</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Color
> Type</td><td>RGB</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Compression</td><td>Deflate/Inflate</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Filter</td><td>Adaptive</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Interlace</td><td>Noninterlaced</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Image
> Size</td><td>2448x3264</td></tr>\n<tr><td>Megapixels</td><td>8.0</td></tr>\n</table>\n'
> 
> 
>  <!-- /home/jason/Pictures/kitty_mask.png --> <table> <tr><td>ExifTool
> Version Number</td><td>10.80</td></tr> <tr><td>File
> Name</td><td>kitty_mask.png</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Directory</td><td>/home/jason/Pictures</td></tr> <tr><td>File
> Size</td><td>25 kB</td></tr> <tr><td>File Modification
> Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:02 09:35:00+01:00</td></tr> <tr><td>File
> Access Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:09 16:23:24+01:00</td></tr>
> <tr><td>File Inode Change Date/Time</td><td>2018:07:02
> 09:35:00+01:00</td></tr> <tr><td>File
> Permissions</td><td>rw-r--r--</td></tr> <tr><td>File
> Type</td><td>PNG</td></tr> <tr><td>File Type
> Extension</td><td>png</td></tr> <tr><td>MIME
> Type</td><td>image/png</td></tr> <tr><td>Image
> Width</td><td>2448</td></tr> <tr><td>Image
> Height</td><td>3264</td></tr> <tr><td>Bit Depth</td><td>8</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Color Type</td><td>RGB</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Compression</td><td>Deflate/Inflate</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Filter</td><td>Adaptive</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Interlace</td><td>Noninterlaced</td></tr> <tr><td>Image
> Size</td><td>2448x3264</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Megapixels</td><td>8.0</td></tr> </table>
```

Comment: If you're going to call exiftool, then I would suggest removing the `-h` option.  This would give you the raw output so you don't need to parse out the html, just the tags you would need.